# How to make div background sit on top?

Tags: html, css, prestashop

I'm making a modal form. This is what happens when I open my modal:
[image]

As you can see logo image, search, meniu and cart is on top of my modal transparent background.
Here is my **HTML** code:

```
<div id="offerModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="closeBtn" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <h2 class="modal-header-top">OFFER YOUR PRICE</h2>
      <hr class="hr">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **CSS** code:

```
.modal{ 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1000; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


.modal-content{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

So how to fix this problem?

Comment: and the css for the header ? maybe the z-index is bigger

Comment: probably, it's a problem of z-index. What is the link for test?

Comment: Try just doing `z-index:99999;` on that modal, that should do it.

Comment: without the rules for those elements, we're just going to be guessing at what is causing the z-index shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, you will want to do:

```
.modal { 
    z-index: 99999; 
}
```

If this fails, then it may be worth decreasing the `z-index` on the logo, search bar and cart area classes to 1.

Comment: Thank you! header area z-index was set to 10. I've changed it into 1 and everything works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try going:

```
.modal{ 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 99999; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

If there is third party CSS z-index may be set somewhere else but it's hard to say with what's provided.

Answer (score 0):

[W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)
Try this code

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1050;
outline: 0;
display:black;
```